# Cannot access function in latest version of GitHub gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mindbody

I am trying to use the [MindBody Gem](https://github.com/wingrunr21/mindbody-api) but when I attempt to run: `$ gem install mindbody-api` I see the error:

```
$ gem install mindbody-api
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'mindbody-api' (>= 0) in any repository
```

I've been able to get it working in my gemfile by including the path of the GitHub page: `gem 'mindbody-api', :git => 'git://github.com/wingrunr21/mindbody-api.git'` and I am successful when I run `bundle install` but I've noticed that my version is missing a function that is present in the GitHub Repo, specifically:

```
MindBody::Services::SaleService.checkout_shopping_cart(search_creds)
NoMethodError: undefined method `checkout_shopping_cart' for MindBody::Services::SaleService:Class
```

despite the function being listed on the [GitHub repo SaleService page](https://github.com/wingrunr21/mindbody-api/blob/master/lib/mindbody-api/services/sale_service.rb).  Any idea what I should try next?

Comment: Where did you run the code snipped that showed the `NoMethodError` ? Also would you be able to provide the output of `bundle show mindbody-api`?

Comment: It shows me "rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@awaken/bundler/gems/mindbody-api-579af18314d2"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your comment under the question it shows that you have older version of the gem:
`rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@awaken/bundler/gems/mindbody-api-579af18314d2`.

So if you browse the repo at this point of time (`579af18314d2`) you will see that the method does not exist yet - [link](https://github.com/wingrunr21/mindbody-api/blob/579af18314d211c9f387a4f2068b6bc23a95e438/lib/mindbody-api/services/sale_service.rb)

In order to fix it you need to update it to  thelatest version, which you can do by:

```
bundle update --source mindbody-api
```

Also to verify that you have the latest version when you do `bundle show mindbody-api` it should show something like: `.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@awaken/bundler/gems/mindbody-api-f58110f2b255`

Comment: is there a way to do this directly in the gemfile?  I've trying uninstalling and reinstalling but seem to constantly end up with the same version

Comment: I was able to update using `bundle update --source mindbody`.  Please add to your response

Comment: sure. Change the line in the Gemfile to: `gem 'mindbody-api', :git => 'git://github.com/wingrunr21/mindbody-api.git', :ref => 'f58110f2b255'`

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the install:

The only version released is an alpha release, that's why you can't install it. You can, however, install the alpha version with:

```
gem install mindbody-api -v 1.0.1.alpha
```

Regarding the method missing:

It appears there is a bug in the way the operations are loaded. I was able to get the method loaded under certain circumstances (cloning & building myself, I think) but even then the behavior wasn't consistent.

The gem hasn't had any significant major updates in a few years. It's not clear if the gem is maintained but I think your best bet might be to create a github repo issue, or fork & fix it yourself.

Comment: hmm I get the same response for all of those functions.  `get_all_opertations` throws a `NoMethodError` as well

Comment: @JeremyThomas you're right, I tried it on a different machine and I get that same error as well. It's possible that the published version doesn't match the repository version. I may have confused my testing when building the gem from the repo, versus the installed gem. I'm updating my answer to remove that check and leave it at simple "There's a bug". The gem doesn't have any recent major activity so it may be necessary to do some refactoring to make this work.